# SendKeys.SendWait method in C#, emulating CTRL+C

Tags: c#, sendkeys

I'm trying to hold down CTRL while C is pressed but I can't get it work.
I've read [SendKeys Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k3w7761b%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) but still, it doesn't work.

Thats what I've tried:

```
SendKeys.SendWait("^C");
SendKeys.SendWait("{^C}");
SendKeys.SendWait("^{C}");
SendKeys.SendWait("^(C)");
SendKeys.SendWait("(^{C})");
```

Answer (score 8):

You need to put in parenthesis. Example:

```
SendKeys.SendWait("^(c)");
```

Notice that c should be lowercase. It is case sensitive

Answer (score 2):

use + instead of ^ for shift and put in parenthesis. (^ for control and + for shift; in your question you said shift). And remember c must be in lowercase.

```
SendKeys.SendWait("+(c)");
```

Comment: Sorry, mistake in a question (edited right now), i ment Ctrl (which is ^)

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to do SHIFT while pressing C, you're using the wrong codes. ^ is CTRL. Shift is +.

Comment: Sorry, mistake in a question (edited right now), i ment Ctrl (which is ^)

Answer (score 0):

You should use a lower case 'c'.

This should work just fine: `SendKeys.SendWait("^c");`

Comment: How is this different from [the top-voted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34786914/3025856)? I get that you're not using the inner parenthesis, but in terms of functional differences, isn't your suggestion identical?

Comment: You are right, but in my experience my answer is slightly more clear and to the point. However, it is a bit of a duplicate answer. Should I delete mine?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30677652)